# Better way to write list of places program

Tags: javascript, beginner, meteor

I wrote some code using meteor, which is working, but I don't know if I did it the best way.  I'm asking for opinions on other ways to perform this task.

It's just a list of places.  You can fill the textfield with a place and it'll appear on the list.  You have an option to remove the place by clicking on the "x".

Very simple, but I'm new to meteor.

### place_list.js

```
   Places = new Meteor.Collection('placesNew');
   if(Meteor.isClient){
     Template.places_list.places = function(){
       return Places.find({},{sort:{name: 1}});
      console.log(Template.place_list.place); 
     }

   Template.places_list.events({
     'blur .place': function (obj) {
       Places.insert({name: obj.target.value});
     },
     'click .plc_remove': function(obj){
       Places.remove( obj.toElement.attributes['data-ref'].value);
     }
   });
}
```

### place_list.html

```
<head>
  <title>Place List</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Place List :</h1>  
  {{> places_list}}
</body>
<template name="places_list">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Insert a place here" class="place" />
  <ul>
  {{#each places}}
     <li> {{ name}} | <a class="plc_remove" data-ref="{{_id}}" href="#">x</a> | </li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

Comment: Would you prefer a new tag for meteor.js?

Comment: Yep! it's sounds greate... or just a meteor tag, like stackoverflow.

Comment: It looks good to me. No obvious errors or gotchas.

Comment: I think that you are missing a `{` somewhere or you have an extra floating at the end of your .js

Answer (score 1):

Great start! You're very close. I changed things around a little bit, and added an extra template and a separate event map for that template. This should make it easier to understand, and it means you don't have to store the place's id in a data attribute. Check it out:

```
Places = new Meteor.Collection('places');

if(Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.places_list.places = function () {
        return Places.find({}, { sort: { name: 1 } });
    }

    Template.places_list.events({
        'keypress #place': function (evt) {
            if (evt.which === 13) {
                // The user pressed enter
                Places.insert({ name: evt.currentTarget.value });
                place.currentTarget.value = ''; // Reset the text input
            }
        }
    });

    Template.place_item.events({
        'click .plc_remove': function () {
            Places.remove(this._id); // Access the document fields with this.foo
        }
    });
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>Place List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Place List :</h1>  
    {{> places_list}}
</body>

<template name="places_list">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Insert a place here" id="place" />

    <ul>
        {{#each places}}
            {{> place_item}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>

<template name="place_item">
    <li> {{ name}} | <a class="plc_remove" href="#">x</a> | </li>
</template>
```